# Extra spaces in a pre tag

Tags: json, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using an express-handlebars. When I'm trying to output a JSON-string in html tag `pre`, it breaks down. I found out about `preventIndent` option, bot it doesn't help.

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
        compilerOptions: {
            preventIndent: true
        },
        extname: '.hbs',
        partialsDir: ...
    }));
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem and investigate...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I just updated `express-handlebars` to 2.0.0